# How can I share this local site to not use a sub directory?

Tags: server, apache2, localhost

I'm working on a site locally that's just sitting in a folder:

> localhost/tempplace

How can I route, with Apache2, that to be like:

> tempplace:8890

Or just something so it's not a sub directory? It's making local development very frustrating.

Comment: we understand your feeling. But in a site like this it is advised to use good language.

Comment: What if you don't have access to change your apache config files (like shared hosting)?

Answer (score 4):

You need to do two things, the first is to make an apache2 virtual host that will respond to the domain name given and the port used; so in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/tempplace.conf` which should be symlinked to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-tempplace` you should have something like this:

```
<VirtualHost tempplace.localhost:80>
    DocumentRoot /www/example1
    ServerName tempplace.localhost

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

Once you have that part you can restart your apache2 server. Next you have to enable a localhost hostname, to do this you edit the file `/etc/hosts` and add as follows:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain localhost tempplace.localhost
```

This effectively adds the `tempplace.localhost` resolve to your local dns and means that browsing to it will point to localhost. You should then be able to browse your Apache virtual server on your localhost without resorting to different ports.

Answer (score 0):

Let me add some points to In Protest's answer.

1). enable the apache userdir module.

```
sudo  a2enmod userdir
```

this will enable apache userdir module. Now you can put the contents of website in `~/public_html/` or whatever inside your home directory.

Note: The default folder is `~/public_html`

2). Make necessary changes to `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/userdir.conf`.

3). Restart the apache

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Now you can access the site by navigating your browser to http://ip-address/~username.

4) Set a virtual host for this site as in In Protest'answer

If you are looking to run php files you need to do one more step

edit the `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf` and comment the following lines:

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        <Directory /home/*/public_html>
            php_admin_value engine Off
        </Directory>
    </IfModule>
```

Then restart the apache.

Thats it. You are done.

Ref:https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UserDirectoryPHP

Hope this helps. If you face any difficulties feel free to post it here.

Comment: -1 , This doesn't seem to answer his question at all, which is how to run the site *without* a leading prefix. I suspect his app could be rewritten to use relative links, but thats another matter.

Comment: yea. That what i said . But this time the the document root will be inside in home directory so that you don't want to give permission to the user to edit /var/www